# How to convert a Quaternion to an Euler Angle(Vector3) in Java?

Tags: java, 3d

I am trying to work with javax.vecmath classes such as quat4f and vector3f. Whenever I read a quaternion(ex: quat.x), it comes out as a float clamped between 0 and 1. Is there a way to convert quaternions to euler. Stuff like this(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) doesn't make much sense to me so don't point out crazy complicated articles.

Comment: Please post the code you have attempted.  This is not a code writing service.

Comment: Im not asking for written code i am asking for ways i can convert a quaternion to a euler angle. I am looking for things like math equations or something not code.

Comment: Did you try typing those words into Google?  This is the first thing that comes up when I do: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles